# Jquery validate plugin. Messages not visible until field loses focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using the jquery validate plugin.  I've found an issue that only occurs once I deploy my site and even then it appears to be intermittent.  When I submit the form with invalid fields it prevents submission but none of the invalid fields display messages that indicate they are invalid.  If I put my cursor in the field and then tab out the validation message appears.  It also appears that taking a screen capture updates the display and causes the message to appear.  The issue occurs on multiple field types, but here is one as an example.

```
<input name="ProjectDescription" class="required" id="ProjectDescription" style="text-transform: uppercase;" type="text" maxLength="15" value=""/>
```

Here is my validate call.

```
        $('#RequestForm').validate({
        ignore: ":hidden",
        ignoreTitle: true,
        submitHandler: function () {
            var f = $('#RequestForm');
            var action = '/Request/Request'
            var serializedForm = f.serialize();
            $.post(action, serializedForm,
                function (rtn) {
                    $("#Submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                    if (rtn.Success == true) {
                        var data = rtn.Result;
                        $('form')[0].reset();
                        $.jGrowl("Submitted Successfully", { life: 10000 });
                    }
                    else {
                        $.jGrowl(rtn.ErrorMessage, { sticky: true });
                    }
                });
            $("#Submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            return false;
        },
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            debugger
            console.log(validator);
        }
    });
```

And my button handler

```
    $('#Submit').click(function () {
        $('#RequestForm').submit();

    });
```

I've not been able to replicate this issue in a fiddle or anywhere else.  During the course of writing this request it's stopped occurring again, but I've not made any code changes.  Any help on what could cause this kind of behavior would be appreciated.  I'm testing primarily in IE 9

Update:

I've been unable to find any way to reliably replicate the issue but will keep trying to create a fiddle if I can.  During the same browsing session it will suddenly start working.  Often I can get the behavior to appear for another 3-4 attempts by closing and re-opening the browser.  Based on the comments I've tried calling blur and hide/show on the field.  Neither of these causes the error message to appear.  Either pressing the print screen button or placing my cursor in the field and pressing tab reliably causes the validation message to appear.  Some additional information about the solution:

The page is generated by MVC 3.
I use javascript and ajax quite a bit to show/hide fields.
The show/hide of fields is happening in ajax callback.

This particular field is being shown/hidden by

```
                       if (project.PAContractClassID == "CAPITAL") { // capital
                            $('.capitalOnly').show();
                            $('.expenseOnly').hide();
                        }
                        else if (project.PAContractClassID == "EXPENSE") {  // expense
                            $('.expenseOnly').show();
                            $('.capitalOnly').hide();
                        }
```

My code from MVC to generate the field

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectDescription, new { @name="ProjectDescription", @class = "required", maxlength = "15", style = "text-transform:uppercase;" })
```

Comment: If it's intermittent, then I don't really know how anyone can help you.  We have to see the issue in order to fix it.  It's also not really appropriate for anyone to post random guesses and suggestions as an answer.  Also show more HTML code... enough to construct a concise example.  `form` tags and your `submit` button?

Comment: I'll make a couple suggestions here.  What happens when you declare your rules inside `.validate()` rather than inline HTML?  Also, try changing the spelling of `maxLength` to `maxlength`.

Comment: If your `submit` button is contained inside the `<form></form>`, then there is absolutely no need to provide a `click` handler function to submit the form.

Comment: @Sparky - I've seen a number of questions with good, useful answers that consist of "This could be your problem.  If it is, this is the solution."

Comment: @BenBarden, Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [explore the Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)....  SO is about concise answers to concise questions.  This question seems to contain no broken code, therefore everything posted would potentially be random noise.  My comments are only meant to get the OP to improve the question to avoid down-voting and closure.

Comment: @BenBarden, I've provided helpful comments to the OP, I didn't down-vote it, and I'm not stopping anyone from answering.  I've also answered [almost 300 questions about this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A594235+%5Bjquery-validate%5D) and I've never seen an "intermittent" issue reported.  The OP not only says it's intermittent, it _only_ happens after he deploys his page.  That's really nothing for anyone to work with here.  Again, if you disagree with my comments, feel free to post any complaints over at the Meta site as comments are not the place to debate this issue.

Comment: I believe I may at least know the source of your intermittent behavior.  If I recall a similar situation I ran into previously, fields that had been interacted with prior to submission would validate correctly, while those that were left blank and untouched were not.  Regardless, I strongly suspect that this is a matter of browser caching (which IE does quite a lot of)  I seem to recall a kludge answer of calling blur() on all input fields in the invalidHandler, and a fix involving `.hide().show()` - though that may have been solving a different problem.

Comment: Sparky.  I've tried changing the spelling of max length and putting my rules inside validate.  Those didn't resolve it.

Comment: And what about my third comment?  **If your submit button is contained inside the `<form></form>`, then there is absolutely no need to provide a click handler function to submit the form.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing I isolated a reference to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax that was in my _Layout.cshtml as interfering with jquery validate's behavior.  After removing the reference to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax I haven't gotten the error again.  I'm going to continue doing some testing to see if the order I add these references makes a difference, but I didn't want to leave the question unanswered.  Thank you for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto Sparky: If your submit button is contained inside the `<form></form>`, then there is absolutely no need to provide a click handler function to submit the form.

If you're not using a submit button, but just a `type=button` instead, then try using `type=submit` and see if theproblem goes away.